# how to extract word from string (TEXT/HTML) in java using either words or characters as reference to extracted

Tags: java

how to extract word from string using either words as reference to extracted

```
String str = "I'm eating filet-o-fish and hashed potatoes for breakfast";
```

between "eating"&"for breakfast" how to extract "filet-o-fish and hashed potatoes";
جزاكم خيرا
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Please only use English on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` along with regex `eating\\s*(.*)\\s*for breakfast`, which is a capturing group between the 2 keywords

```
String str = "I'm eating filet-o-fish and hashed potatoes for breakfast";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("eating\\s*(.*)\\s*for breakfast").matcher(str);

if (m.find()) {
    String inside = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(inside); // filet-o-fish and hashed potatoes
}
```